# I need some help getting this turtle graphic to move on the y-axis

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am having some trouble getting my turtle to move on the y-axis for this game for class. I need it to be able to respond to borders of my map and move in all directions. I plan to have multiple levels as well. I am not able to use `pygame` and very few other modules for this project.

````
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('black')
line = turtle.Turtle()


#LVL 1
def level1():
   line.hideturtle()
   line.speed(999)
   line.pencolor("white")
   line.penup()
   line.goto (-400,400)
   line.pendown()
   line.goto (400,400)
   line.goto (400,100)
   line.penup()
   line.goto(400,-100)
   line.pendown()
   line.goto (400,-400)
   line.goto (-400,-400)
   line.goto (-400,400)

def level2():
   line.hideturtle()
   line.speed(999)
   line.pencolor("white")
   line.penup()
   line.goto (-400,400)
   line.pendown()
   line.goto(-100,400)
   line.penup()
   line.goto(100,400)
   line.pendown()
   line.goto (400,400)
   line.goto (400,-400)
   line.goto(100,-400)
   line.penup()
   line.goto(-100,-400)
   line.pendown()
   line.goto (-400,-400)
   line.goto(-400,-100)
   line.penup()
   line.goto(-400,100)
   line.pendown()
   line.goto (-400,400)


fred = turtle.Turtle()
fred.penup()
fred.goto(0,0)
fred.shape('square')
fred.color('white')
fred.penup()
fred.delay = 0.1
fred.direction = "Stop"


#Set Up (Controls)
wn.listen()
#Works well (Avoid Editing)
def ahead():
   fred.forward(10)
   if fred.xcor() > 390:
       fred.backward(10)


def behind():
   fred.backward(10)
   if fred.xcor() < -390:
      fred.forward(10)

def upd():
  if fred.ycor() > 380:
       fred.speed(9999)
       fred.left(90)
       fred.backward(10)
       fred.right(90)
       fred.speed(1)
  temp = fred.ycor()
  fred.goto (fred.ycor+10, fred.xcor)

def downd():
   if fred.ycor() < -380:
           fred.speed(9999)
           fred.left(90)
           fred.forward(10)
           fred.right(90)
           fred.speed(1)
   fred.speed(9999)
   fred.left(90)
   fred.backward(10)
   fred.right(90)
   fred.speed(1)

neghun = -100
hun = 100

def game():
   level1()
   if fred.ycor() > -100 and fred.ycor() < 100 and fred.ycor() == 370:
        print ("test")
game()

wn.onkey(behind,"a")
wn.onkey(ahead,"d")
wn.onkey(upd,"w")
wn.onkey(downd,"s")
wn.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 0):

In your `upd()` function, these two lines are a problem:

```
  temp = fred.ycor()
  fred.goto (fred.ycor+10, fred.xcor)
```

we can ignore the first line as it effectively does nothing.  The second line invokes `fred.ycor` and `fred.xcor`  when it really wants `fred.ycor()` and `fred.xcor()`.  And, it reverses the `x` and `y` arguments to `goto()`.  We can simplify this function to something like:

```
def upd():
    if fred.ycor() < 370:
        fred.sety(fred.ycor() + 10)
```

Your entire code similarly simplified:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def level1():
    line.penup()
    line.goto(-400, 400)
    line.pendown()
    line.goto(400, 400)
    line.goto(400, 100)
    line.penup()
    line.goto(400, -100)
    line.pendown()
    line.goto(400, -400)
    line.goto(-400, -400)
    line.goto(-400, 400)

def level2():
    line.penup()
    line.goto(-400, 400)
    line.pendown()
    line.goto(-100, 400)
    line.penup()
    line.goto(100, 400)
    line.pendown()
    line.goto(400, 400)
    line.goto(400, -400)
    line.goto(100, -400)
    line.penup()
    line.goto(-100, -400)
    line.pendown()
    line.goto(-400, -400)
    line.goto(-400, -100)
    line.penup()
    line.goto(-400, 100)
    line.pendown()
    line.goto(-400, 400)

def ahead():
    if fred.xcor() < 370:
        fred.forward(10)

def behind():
    if fred.xcor() > -370:
        fred.backward(10)

def upd():
    if fred.ycor() < 370:
        fred.sety(fred.ycor() + 10)

def downd():
    if fred.ycor() > -370:
        fred.sety(fred.ycor() - 10)

def game():
    level1()

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(850, 850)
screen.bgcolor('black')

line = Turtle()
line.hideturtle()
line.speed('fastest')
line.pencolor('white')

fred = Turtle()
fred.shape('square')
fred.color('white')
fred.penup()

game()

screen.onkey(behind, 'a')
screen.onkey(ahead, 'd')
screen.onkey(upd, 'w')
screen.onkey(downd, 's')
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```